# XeTeX \left and \right problem

Tags: math-mode, xetex, delimiters, unicode-math

I have a problem with the `〈` and  `〉` symbols (Unicode encoding: 27E8 and 27E9) which replace the `\langle` and `\rangle`, when I try to combine them with `\left` and `\right` commands. The following examples gives error although, if I change `\left〈` some formula `\right〉` with `\left\langle` some formula `\right\rangle` or `\left(` some formula `\right)`, it works.  What is more interesting is that if I change `〈〉` with `‖` (Unicode encoding: 2016 ) the following example also works.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO}
\setmathfont{lmmath-regular.otf}

\begin{document}
 bla bla bla bla
 blabla blaaa
    \[
       \left‹ \dfrac{\frac{x+2}{y}+\frac{3}{4}}{x^2+y^2-5} \right›
    \]
bla bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

I already defined the commands `\〈` and `\〉` like this

```
\newcommand\〈{\langle}
\newcommand\〉{\rangle}
```

but I think this symbols should work with `\left` and `\right` in the same manner like `|`, `{`, `[` and of course `‖`. I use Kile for the front-end and TeXLive 2011 manually installed on a x64 machine (Kubuntu operating system).

Because I can not answer my questions (for now)  I'll put something here, so sorry for the long post.

It seems that XeTeX (or XeLaTeX, I'm new so sorry for may ignorance) produces the same output for `\left< some formula \right>` (where `< >` are the common less and greater) and `\left\langle some formula \right\rangle` but a totally different output for `< some formula >` and `\langle some formula \rangle`. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
 \XeTeXdelcodenum`‹=\XeTeXdelcodenum`<
 \XeTeXdelcodenum`›=\XeTeXdelcodenum`>
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO}
\setmathfont{lmmath-regular.otf}

\begin{document}
bla bla bla bla
 blabla blaaa
 \begin{gather}
\left< \dfrac{\frac{x+2}{y}+\frac{3}{4}}{x^2+y^2-5} \right>\\
\left\langle \dfrac{\frac{x+2}{y}+\frac{3}{4}}{x^2+y^2-5} \right\rangle\\
\langle ϕ(x-k),Ψ(x)\rangle\\
<ϕ(x-k),Ψ(x)>\\
‹ϕ(x-k),Ψ(x)›\\
\left\langle ϕ(x-k),Ψ(x) \right \rangle\\
\left< ϕ(x-k),Ψ(x) \right>
\end{gather}
bla bla bla bla $<  ‹$
\end{document}
```

And about the 〈〉, I will drop using them, in the first place they do not make the desirable output (although in the unimath-symbols documentations they are represented with the `\langle`, `\rangle` Macros ), and they are cumbersome.

My question is now, whey 〈〉 do not behave like the macro command in the documentation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX Stack Exchange! If you haven't already done so, please consider registering with the site to gain certain "privileges" such as editing rights on your own question. Incidentally, to improve its readability, I've moved the code you provided in the comments area to the main body of your question.

Comment: This seems like a bug. Please file a report at https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues.

Comment: Thanks for copying `\langle` and `\rangle` as text! This was the most accessible link for copying them into a text editor. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently **unicode-math** doesn't assign a delimiter code to `〈` and `〉` (it should, in my opinion). Add the following magic code after having loaded **unicode-math**

```
\XeTeXdelcodenum`〈=\XeTeXdelcodenum`<
\XeTeXdelcodenum`〉=\XeTeXdelcodenum`>
```

Now `\left〈` and `\right〉` will work.

One has to pay attention to the characters used. For example the following are *different*:

```
‹〈
› 〉
```

In the first line we have U+2039 (SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK) and U+3008 (LEFT ANGLE BRACKET); in the second line there are U+203A (SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK) and U+3009 (RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET). Only U+3008 and U+3009.

In your example you are confusing the two. However it's possible to use also U+2039 and U+203A for the angle brackets:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO}
\setmathfont{lmmath-regular.otf}

\XeTeXmathcodenum`‹=\XeTeXmathcodenum`〈 % make U+2039 the same as U+3008
\XeTeXmathcodenum`›=\XeTeXmathcodenum`〉 % make U+203A the same as U+3009
\XeTeXdelcodenum`〈=\XeTeXdelcodenum`<   % use U+3008 after \left or \right
\XeTeXdelcodenum`〉=\XeTeXdelcodenum`>   % use U+3009 after \left or \right
\XeTeXdelcodenum`‹=\XeTeXdelcodenum`<   % use U+2039 after \left or \right
\XeTeXdelcodenum`›=\XeTeXdelcodenum`>   % use U+203A after \left or \right

\begin{document}
bla bla bla bla
 blabla blaaa
 \begin{gather}
\left〈\dfrac{\frac{x+2}{y}+\frac{3}{4}}{x^2+y^2-5} \right 〉\\
\left‹\dfrac{\frac{x+2}{y}+\frac{3}{4}}{x^2+y^2-5} \right ›\\
\left\langle \dfrac{\frac{x+2}{y}+\frac{3}{4}}{x^2+y^2-5}\right\rangle\\
\left< \dfrac{\frac{x+2}{y}+\frac{3}{4}}{x^2+y^2-5}\right>\\
〈a〉\\
‹a›
\end{gather}
bla bla bla bla $< 〈 ‹$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your approach but now in the pdf output the symbols are gone completely. Although you're answer helped me to identify useful informations for me (so thank you very much).

Comment: Thanks about your patience and guiding. You are right about the fact that I was using the wrong Unicode character. This is a bug but not for the TeX(XeTeX) but for the Linux keyboard mapping program. And again thank you.